# Batch won't return what it's suppose to

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm still pretty new to this, but I'm trying to start `server.exe` with some parameters, but the `%cmdline%` does not return.

NOTE: When I replace `%cmdline%` with `-logfile=server/output_log.txt -batchmode -nographics -dedicated -configfile=server/serverconfig.xml` it works fine, but I need it to read from the data file.

**BATCH**

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('type data.dat ^| findstr "EXENAME="') do set exename=%%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('type data.dat ^| findstr "EXEPATH="') do set exepath=%%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('type data.dat ^| findstr "CMDLINE="') do set cmdline=%%i
start /normal %exepath%%exename% %cmdline%
```

**data.dat**

```
EXENAME=server.exe
EXEPATH=./server/
CMDLINE=-logfile=server/output_log.txt -batchmode -nographics -dedicated -configfile=server/serverconfig.xml
```

Comment: if you're new then it's much simpler to just avoid cmd and learn powershell instead

Comment: What about just, 1: `@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In ("data.dat") Do @Set "%%G"`,  2: `@Start "" "%EXEPATH%%EXENAME%" %CMDLINE%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('type data.dat ^| findstr "CMDLINE="') do set cmdline=%%i
```

is parsing the line of `DATA.DAT` containing `CMDLINE=` using the equal sign `=` as delimiter, and the line contains other equal signs.

a simple solution is to instruct FOR to return the first and the rest of tokens and then take only the second (that contains all the tokens except the first)

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('type data.txt ^| findstr "CMDLINE="') do set cmdline=%%j
```